# Highstock not showing all series

Tags: php, highcharts

I am passing Highstock/Highcharts three separate series of data via PHP and for some reason only one series is displayed when the chart is loaded. Here is an example of what my HTML output looks like now: http://bit.ly/15D3Dhi and here is what my full PHP code looks like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$stocks = array('MSFT' => 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT', 'AAPL' => 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL', 'FB' => 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FB', 'ZNGA' => 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ZNGA');
$stocks_data = array();

foreach ($stocks as $key=>$stock) {
    $fh = fopen($stock, 'r');
    $header = fgetcsv($fh);

    $varname = $key . '_data';

    $$varname  = array();
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        ${$varname}[count($$varname)] = array_combine($header, $line);
    }

    fclose($fh);
}

foreach($MSFT_data as $val){
    $MSFT[]   = array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
}
$MSFT = json_encode($MSFT);

foreach($AAPL_data as $val){
    $AAPL[]   = array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
}
$AAPL = json_encode($AAPL);

foreach($FB_data as $val){
    $FB[]   = array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
}
$FB = json_encode($FB);

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Highcharts + PHP + Stock Data
        </title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container'
                    },

                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 4
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                            }
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'silver'
                        }]
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            compare: 'percent'
                        }
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },

                    series: [{
                name: 'MSFT',
                data: <?php echo $MSFT; ?>
            }, {
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: <?php echo $AAPL; ?>
            }, {
                name: 'FB',
                data: <?php echo $FB; ?>
            }]
                });     
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 600px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone look at my code and see why only one series is showing up? If you look at the source of my HTML output, all data appears to have been passed in the same way, so it's not clear to me why only one series is displayed.

Thanks and let me know if you have any questions or need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked at it, and the first thing I noticed is the code is quite clean, but there is a JS error:

```
Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15
Title: Highcharts expects data to be sorted
```

Then I noticed FB is the only one that shows up, but expanding the date range lets you see FB and another series, so the Y axis is to blame.

Out of whim I decided to fix the JS error first, and somehow the Y-axis solved itself. So looks like the JS error is the culprit.

EDITED: Using the much faster array_reverse instead of array_unshift per 585connor's suggestion:

```
foreach($MSFT_data as $val){
    $MSFT[] = array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
}
$MSFT = json_encode(array_reverse($MSFT));

foreach($AAPL_data as $val){
    $AAPL[] = array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
}
$AAPL = json_encode(array_reverse($AAPL));

foreach($FB_data as $val){
    $FB[] = array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
}
$FB = json_encode(array_reverse($FB));

foreach($ZNGA_data as $val){
    $ZNGA[] = array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
}
$ZNGA = json_encode(array_reverse($ZNGA));
```

Comment: Could I use array_reverse in this situation? Would that be more efficient than array_unshift?

Comment: You're absolutely right, my local tests (4 attempts each, execution time in seconds including fetching the csv from yahoo): array_unshift -
13.509613990784,
12.721925020218,
13.020925998688,
13.345903873444.

array-reverse - 
6.1595048904419,
5.833899974823,
6.436450958252,
6.3766050338745.